# Convexity and Connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that all convex sets are connected?  This seems intuitively true, but I would like to know if it is, then why? And if not, why not?  In other words, is showing that a set is convex sufficient to show that it is connected?

Comment: Hint: use path connectedness.

Comment: Is this a pure topological question, or a topological vector space question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $C$ be a convex set. Suppose is not connected then there are to disjoint non empty open sets $U,V$ so that $U\cup V=C$. Pick points $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ since $C$ is convex the line segment between them is contained in $C$, i.e., the function $f: [0,1]\to C$ defined $f(t)=tx+(1-t)y$.
Note that $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ would show that $[0,1]$ is not connected a contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the set X={a,b} endowed with discrete topology and a order relation. It is convex but not connected...

Comment: You are misunderstanding the notion of *convexity* used in the question.